# What are good patterns for resolving the gap between new and old API payloads (in an iOS timeline TableView)?

Tags: ios, pagination, nsfetchedresultscontroller

This question MAY not lend itself to concrete answers that this site prefers, and strays probably a little to far into the UX realm, but I haven't found a better space to ask this kind of question and get a reasonable amount of eyes on it. Ultimately it's about a good iOS programming pattern to handle this situation.

When building an iOS apps I have often needed to create a Twitter or Facebook–like feed interface, or had a situation where I have to display a large list of (potentially) continually updating items. NSFetchedResultsController is naturally a pretty good fit for this kind of thing, but I have run into the problem of resolving the gap between old (stale) data previously loaded (and usually persisted) and new data from the API. I want to give the user instant access to the previously loaded data, while loading in the new data, and then handle paginating through any data in between.

I struggle with a great pattern for doing this kind of thing. Some of the better implementations I've seen have been in Twitter for iPhone and Tweetbot. Here's an example pulled from [this uxdesign.com article](http://uxdesign.smashingmagazine.com/2013/05/03/infinite-scrolling-get-bottom/) on infinite loading:

[image: Handling the gap]

This problem can present itself all over the place. Timelines like Twitter or Facebook are obvious, but it also could present itself, for instance, when displaying a user's friends/connections, or some other large list of data. Previously you may have fetched a lot of results (in my case, usually into core data), that you can display right away. At the same time, you want to provide fresh data. In a lot of situations you will want to paginate through that data, not just get it all in one lump sum.

So what's the right approach here? The best approach I've been able to come up with solves for the timeline scenario, which is probably the more common scenario.

Basically my approach is to instantly display old data, and then request the most recent data from the timeline, and always passing the highest (newest) ID I have to the API. This may produce a gap between the new and the old depending on the pagination amount, so once you scroll to the final cell in the new page of data (or ideally, some loading indicator in between the new and old) you then request the next batch of data, either requesting the next page, or passing the low and high ID's (from the items surrounding your loading row).

This approach is a pain in the ass technically, especially if you wanted to use a NSFetchedResultsController, as you now have to keep an index for the location of your loading bar, and map any index path's in and out of the NSFRC to wrap around your loading cell.

If you don't have an API that accepts high and low ID's, and instead just uses pages, then it also means a lot of network data as you'll end up just paginating right through existing persisted data. So is there a better pattern for this? I know synchronizing data is a deep, never-ending realm, but I'm hoping to hear if others have different patterns.

Comment: Got any new ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: Haven't done this for awhile, but I didn't find any "obvious" pattern other than the solution I described.